# Rails 4: has_one - belongs_to: nested model instance attributes won't assign

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, belongs-to, has-one

I am having this weird issue where instance[:attribute] works on assignment and writing the attribute but instance.attribute, instance.update, etc. , all fails to change the value of the attribute in the model instance.

Here is a user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :api_account, inverse_of: :user, dependent: :destroy

# Other user-specific validations come after
```

Here is the associated api_account:

```
class ApiAccount < ACtiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :api_account
  validates :access_token, presence: true
  validates :user, presence: true,
                   uniqueness: true
```

In the api_account controller, I have:

```
response = ### Some JSON response from a distant server

@api_account = @user.create_api_account(:access_token => response[:access_token])
# -> This doesn't work and does not set the access_token attribute in the database.
# id: 2, access_token: nil, user_id: nil, created...
```

Then I changed that to `@api_account = @user.build_api_account(:access_token => response[:access_token])` and then `user_id: 1` but `access_token: nil`.

In the rails console: `@a = @u.build_api_account` works and `@a[:access_token] = "access_token"` works and save persists that change. But everything else I tried fails.

NOTE: `@a.access_token = "access_token"`, changes the attribute for just `@a.access_token`; but an inspection of @a still shows that the "access_token attribute is `nil`.

The schema for the api_account looks like this:

```
create_table "api_accounts", force: true do |t|
  t.text     "access_token"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "user_id"
end

add_index "api_account", ["user_id"], name: "index_api_accounts_on_user_id"
```

Does anybody know what is going wrong here? User instances work fine - normal attribute manipulation works great. I am totally lost. There is something different with "has_one" and not as much documentation out there as "has_many".

Answer (score 0):

I guess its a mass-assignment issue.

U need to pass the permitted parameters.

pls check this link.

http://blog.trackets.com/2013/08/17/strong-parameters-by-example.html

Comment: I took my time, read that article and implemented `params = ActionController::Parameters.new(api_account: response)` in the controller. However, I cannot seem to pass the error message: "param is missing or the value is empty". Thoughts?